# How to use external JSON-file in Wget HTTP PUT while using Docker environment variables?

Tags: json, linux, docker, dockerfile, wget

## Current situation:

1. A Dockerfile that is based on an Ubuntu image, installs Wget and declares that a bashscript will run when a container is started.
2. A Docker container is started based on the image with the necessary environment variables in the command. These variables will be used inside the Wget command in the bashscript.

   ```
   docker run -i -e ‘ENV_VARIABLE=VALUE’ [imagename]
   ```
3. The container runs the bashscript, containing a Wget HTTP PUT:

   ```
   wget --method=PUT --body-data=”{\“key\”:\”${ENV_VARIABLE}\”}” ……
   ```

## Desired situation:

The current situation works, but I don’t prefer this solution. This is because of the quote-escaping (\”) I have to use.

I tried to solve this by constructing the --body-data as below, with surrounding single quotes.

```
‘{“key”:”${ENV_VARIABLE}”}’
```

However, this will not set the ENV_VARIABLE since the payload is a full String now.

A more preferable solution would be to separate the JSON to a JSON-file, which I can refer to in the Wget call. This arises the following questions:

1. How to refer to the JSON-file? My best guess is to first copy the file on the build of the image into the image and then refer to it via a path in the Wget call, but then again, how do I refer to it?
2. If the above point is correct, will I still be able to refer to the Docker environment variables?

Comment: You will need to write a program to fill in the environment variables in the JSON file.  The shell toolset isn’t great for this for a combination of quoting and escaping reasons, but almost every other language has JSON parsing and serialization support.  This might for example be an excellent first Python project.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion! Good to know that shell wont do the job in this case (I don't have that much experience with it).

Comment: @KeukenkastjeXYZ You can use --body-file instead of --body-data. This accepts the path to a file to read from. The path can be mapped as a volume when you start the container. Is that not what you want? If so and you cannot get it to work let me know and I can write the solution as well.